# How to match a field value from the same document in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I have a below document:

```
{
    "_id" : "bfc523ad-c09d-4be8-99c2-64a709cf95ab",
    "field1" : {
        "c1" : "bfc523ad-c09d-4be8-99c2-64a709cf95ab",
        "c2" : "pl_PowerList_bfc523adc09d4be899c264a709cf95ab",
    },
    "Columns" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "abc49777",
            "lookup":{
                "id":"bfc523ad-c09d-4be8-99c2-64a709cf95ab"
            }

        }, 
        {
            "name" : "abc7846",
            "lookup":{
                "id":"cgc523ad-c09d-4be8-99c2-64a709cf95xy"
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to fetch all the documents where field1.c1 value is equal to Columns.lookup.id (in any one of colums). I tried the below query:

```
db.mycollection.find({$where:"this.field1.c1 == this.Columns.lookup.id"})
```

When I executed the above query I got error saying that field id is undefined. I want all such documents where atleast one column has lookup.id same as that document's field1.c1. How will I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
db.mycollection.find( 
{ $where: 
    function() {
        var array = this.Columns;
        for (var i in array) {
            if(array[i].lookup.id == this.field1.c1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the aggregation framework where you can take advantage of the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline operator. This allows you to recursively descend through the document structure and do some actions based on an evaluation of specified conditions at each level.

Performance using the aggregation framework is greatly enhanced as opposed to using the **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where)** operator.

The concept can be a bit tricky to grasp but basically the operator allows you to proccess the logical condition with the **[`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)** operator and uses the special operations **[`$$KEEP`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** to "keep" the document where the logical condition is true or **[`$$PRUNE`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** to "remove" the document where the condition was false.

This operation is similar to having a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline that selects the fields in the collection and creates a new field that holds the result from the logical condition query and then a subsequent **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**, except that **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** uses a single pipeline stage which restricts contents of the result set based on the access required to view the data and is more efficient.

---

To run a query on all documents where `field1.c1` value is equal to `Columns.lookup.id` (in any one of the colums), include a **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** stage as in the following:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                {
                    "$setIsSubset": [
                        ["$field1.c1"],
                        {
                            "$map": {
                                "input": "$Columns",
                                "as": "col",
                                "in": "$$col.lookup.id"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```